# WCF IDispatchMessageInspector

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

There is a message in the form of a string line that passes all tests. When trying to create out of it and return a message via BeforeSendReply, then flies the signature and the message will not validly. What could be the reason?

How can I create Message from string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the message this way:

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
            string message = buffer.CreateMessage();
            ...
```

Comment: XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(innerXml));
 Message modifiedRequest = Message.CreateMessage(xmlReader, int.MaxValue, reply.Version );
 reply = modifiedRequest;

Comment: XML is a message with Security Header <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security>
      .....
      </o:Security>
      <Action> ...</Action>
      <ActivityId>.....</ActivityId>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <Response></Response>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: signedResponse = Cryptography.MessageSigner.Sign(msg.ToString());
 var innerXml = signedResponse.InnerXml;
                XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(innerXml));
                Message modifiedRequest = Message.CreateMessage(xmlReader, int.MaxValue, reply.Version );
                reply = modifiedRequest;

Comment: I get the message and then sign it after processing. I just need to get it back.

Comment: have anyone any idea ?